# How can I get the value in this array?

Tags: php, arrays

I cannot figure out getting the string 'foo' printed from an array. How can I just print the value in 'tags'?

```
print_r(array_values($res));

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [tags] => foo
        )

)
```

Comment: Do you have a guess?  And why `array_values()`?

Comment: Why are you using `array_values`? What does it look like without that?

Comment: [The PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.accessing) should be helpful.

Comment: `var_dump($res['tags']);`

Comment: can you print print_r($res); ?

Comment: @farhadamjady there's another array level before 'tags'

Comment: so `var_dump($res[0]['tags']);` @Don'tPanic

Comment: `$res[0]['tags']`

Comment: `$res` may not actually have a 0 index. Or it might. No way to tell since it's been run through `array_values`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrays work in depth. You can have array that store arrays and so on. If:

```
$res = array ( 0 => array ( ['tags'] => 'foo' ) );
echo $res[0]['tags']; // foo
```

does that make sense?

Also, be careful when using Array and array

[Array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)
 vs [array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array.php)

Comment: Thanks. It's clear now.